# ISaveablePart2 is not working in eclipse 3.x migration

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

In 3.7, we used ISaveablePart2 interface to perform few settings save operation in method isSaveOnCloseNeeded() on view close, but in 3.x migration application, this event is not working.

As application is not pure E4 applicaion( using compat layer), i think ISaveHandler will not work as well. So Please guide me how can i achiveve the same behaviour in 3.X migration to save few settings before view close?

Comment: `ISaveablePart2` still works for 3.x views.

Comment: @greg-449 Just compared the code, In 3.x hideView method was called in workbenchpage on view close but in Compat application HidePart method of PartServiceImpl is getting called instead of WorkBenchPage hidePart. This is the reason in my openion isSaveOnCloseNeeded() method is not getting called in my views. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: PartServiceImpl calls the default save handler installed by WorkbenchWindow which uses SaveablesList to call isSaveOnCloseNeeded.

Comment: In 3.x even method isDirty return false, method isSaveOnCloseNeeded get called but in eclipse 4 due to below code save state is totally depend on isDirty method and if it returns false, eclipse 4 never call is isSaveOnCloseNeeded.


 public boolean savePart(MPart part, boolean confirm) {
  if (!part.isDirty()) {
   return true;
  }

  if (saveHandler != null) {
   return saveHandler.save(part, confirm);
  }
       }